# Windows Server 2019 new install network adapter does not connect

Tags: drivers, connection, windows-server-2019

I installed Windows Server 2019 from scratch on a local machine as a testbed for development. The server is up and running fine but cannot connect to any network. The symptoms are

(1) No wireless connections are showing
(2) the Network services have stopped and cannot be restarted, because, they say, there is no external connection.

I found one recommendation to solve this by installing Network Drivers specific to Windows Server; however this referred to Intel Network adapters but the machine on which I am installing has a Qualcomm adapter. I did try installing the Intel drivers but the installer simply reported

> You have no Intel adapters

The machine is a Lenovo Yoga and has no known hardware faults. I installed Windows Server 2019 over a fresh Windows 10 installation, which connected perfectly to the internet. Thus I'm fairly sure it is either a driver problem, or that there is a setting I am unaware of.

But I haven't been able to find any reference to this issue on the net.

All help welcome